# Populating a SQL Statement based on selection in Excel 2010 VBA Userform

Tags: sql, vba, excel-2010

Okay, I am BRAND NEW to VBA and SQL and programming in general, and I'm probably already in up to my eyeballs. Be that as it may, I am SO INTRIGUED by the amazing stuff a little VBA and SQL knowledge can do!

So, here's my question:

I created a Userform in Microsoft Excel 2010 that has ComboBoxes/TextBoxes/DTPicker. Ideally what I would like to achieve is if (making this as user friendly as humanly possible) Sally goes in and selects "Sally's Report" and punches in 01/01/2010-05/05/2012 as the date range, a SQL statement is generated that retrieves this data and generates a report.

I currently make the reports using an excel query tool that was created (Basically a textbox userform where you type in the SQL statement, press a command button that initiates the connection, and then run the report). If I could define "Sally's Report" as being "XXX" SQL statement and then run the report based on the combobox selection, they would be able to go in and run the report themselves, and the reports would be available to anyone using the tool.

Any help at all would be GREATLY appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along these lines.  This is a very basic setup since I don't know the table structure you're querying against or the field names on your UserForm.  This code assumes the Combo Box with the various reports is named cboReports and there are two text fields named txtStartDate and txtEndDate which are both populated to query a date range inclusively.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String

    Select Case Me.cboReports
        Case "Sally's Report"
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblSally"
        Case "John's Report"
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblJohn"
        Case Else
            strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblDefault"
    End Select
    If Me.txtStartDate <> vbNullString And Me.txtEndDate <> vbNullString Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE ([DateField] between " & Me.txtStartDate & " and " & Me.txtEndDate & ")"
    End If

    MsgBox "Now it's time to do something with this SQL:" _
         & vbNewLine & strSQL, vbOKOnly

End Sub
```